# How does the re-assignment behaviour emerge?

Tags: python, list, tuples, python-itertools

I'm generating here all possible arrangements of two possible outcomes over 6 positions:

```
paths = list(it.product([['ax','r',[],0], ['ax','l',[],0]], repeat=6))
```

What it should generate is something like:

```
(['ax', 'r', [], 0], ['ax', 'r', [], 0], ['ax', 'r', [], 0], ['ax',    
'r', [], 0], ['ax', 'r', [], 0], ['ax', 'r', [], 0])
```

Which is one element of the list which contains all outcomes.

I'd like to change now the 'ax' string according to the repetitive pattern
`'yp', 'p', 'xp'`

For this I've written something like this:

```
for path in paths:
    axis = 1
    for axis_slice in path:
        if(axis%3 == 1):
            axis_slice[0] = 'yp'
            print(axis_slice[0])
        elif(axis%3 == 2):
            axis_slice[0] = 'p'
            print(axis_slice[0])
        elif(axis%3 == 0):
            axis_slice[0] = 'xp'
            print(axis_slice[0])
        axis+=1
    print("axis: "+str(axis))
    print(path)
```

However the outcome is something like this:

```
(['xp', 'r', [], 0], ['xp', 'r', [], 0], ['xp', 'r', [], 0], ['xp', 'r', [], 0], ['xp', 'r', [], 0], ['xp', 'r', [], 0])
```

Yet the print-statements in the lines above show me that they are correctly assigned, yet going one 'level' back the assignment ('yp', 'p', 'xp') diverges

```
yp
p
xp
yp
p
xp
axis: 7
(['xp', 'r', [], 0], ['xp', 'r', [], 0], ['xp', 'r', [], 0], ['xp', 'r', [], 0], ['xp', 'r', [], 0], ['xp', 'r', [], 0])
```

How does this behaviour emerge? Why is it not visible in the inner loop but in the outer loop? I sense it may have something to do with the order of evaluation and the way tuples/lists are packed.

How can the aimed output be achieved?

Comment: Thank you Bhargav Rao for editing. I shall avoid the mistakes in upcoming post!

Comment: Oh, indeed, the indentation here in stackoverflow was wrong. Thank you for the hint! In the original source the indentation is correct :) Regarding path: each path is a tuple of lists as tuple elements. Yep, lists are mutable while tuples (afaik) are not :)

Comment: Just a thought. Can you not use exact lists in `itertools.product` and reduce the `repeat` so that there wont be any indexing buisness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that all the members of the lists within each `path` in `paths` are the same object.  To verify this for yourself - try:

```
import itertools as it
paths = list(it.product([['ax','r',[],0], ['ax','l',[],0]], repeat=6))
for path in paths:
    print([id(p) for p in path])
```

This prints the unique identifier for each list in the path.  You will see you only ever have two ids - the ids of the original two lists you passed to `it.product`.

So, for example, if you take the first path:

```
(['ax', 'r', [], 0], ['ax', 'r', [], 0], ['ax', 'r', [], 0], ['ax', 'r', [], 0], ['ax', 'r', [], 0], ['ax', 'r', [], 0])
```

It is actually a tuple of 6 references to the same list.  Thus, as you iterate through them, you change the same list each time.  If you `print(path)` instead of `axis_slice[0]` each time you alter it, you will see clearly what is happening - all 6 members of `path` will change each time.  This is a feature of list mutability and using `itertools.product` on a list with mutable members.

This effect is covered really well by Python and SO veteran [Ned Batchelder here](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html).  In particular - look at the slide called "Mutable aliasing" and the following - although the whole article is really worth a read.

How you get around this problem will be highly dependent on the context of this code.

Comment: Excellent explanation. Also many thanks for the resources regarding this effect! In this case also many thanks to  J Richard Snape and C Panda for your contributions!